# how do get link in fonts in custom theme?

Tags: magento2, link

I know in magento2 get media link we can use

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

if i want get link like `.../frontend/customtheme/web/fonts/`. how do get it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

`$this->getViewFileUrl('fonts/...')`